# Google BigQuery: "Invalid source format CSV" when loading data from Datalab

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datalab

I have some files stored in Google Cloud Storage, and I run the following from Google Cloud Datalab's Notebook:

```
path = r'data/path/to/csv/orders_1234'
orders_path = os.path.join(bucket_path, path)
print(orders_path)
dest = 'project_name:dataset_name.orders'
%bigquery load -m append -f csv -d '\t' -S $orders_path -D $dest
```

But I got error **Invalid source format CSV** when running this code. Do you know what I may have done incorrectly here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following [working example](https://github.com/googledatalab/notebooks/blob/master/tutorials/BigQuery/Importing%20and%20Exporting%20Data.ipynb) taken from the [datalab sample notebooks](https://github.com/googledatalab/notebooks) repository.

```
import datalab.bigquery as bq
import datalab.storage as storage
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

# Create the schema, conveniently using a DataFrame example.
%storage read --object gs://cloud-datalab-samples/cars.csv --variable cars
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(cars))
schema = bq.Schema.from_dataframe(df)

# Create the dataset
bq.Dataset('sample').create()

# Create the table
sample_table = bq.Table('sample.cars').create(schema = schema, overwrite = True)

# Load csv file from GCS to Google BigQuery
sample_table.load('gs://cloud-datalab-samples/cars.csv', mode='append',
                  source_format = 'csv', csv_options=bq.CSVOptions(skip_leading_rows = 1))
```

Please note: If you are running an older version of datalab, you may have to use `import gcp.bigquery as bq` instead of `import datalab.bigquery as bq`

You may be able to see additional error message information on the Job History page in the [BigQuery console](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/jobs/).

Comment: Thank you. How do I upgrade datalab so I can use the newest version of it?

Comment: If you deployed Datalab using https://datalab.cloud.google.com/ , visit the Datalab GitHub Issues page (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datalab/issues) and submit an issue to have a new version of datalab published.  If you have installed Datalab locally, or on GCE, then simply rebuild the Datalab image to get the latest version. See the Datalab Getting Started Wiki (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datalab/wiki/Getting-Started) page for more information. Please mark this answer as accepted if it has solved your problem.

Comment: Is it possible to load a zipped csv, using the above load command ? I have checked the documentation, but can't find any thing useful. I am not looking at the streaming option, since this is a batch process.

Comment: Yes, I've just tried it using the following source `'gs://cloud-datalab-samples/cars.csv.gz'` . Make sure to use gzip format as recommended [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/preparing-data-for-loading).